# ExpandableListView doesn't work

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I googled answer for my problem but I didn't find nothing for me.

I want use `ExpandableListView` in my project. I get code from example, but it doesn't work (doesn't expand item view).

This is my xml:

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/exListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:indicatorLeft="250dp"
    android:indicatorRight="300dp" />
```

And this code:

```
mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent.findViewById(R.id.exListView);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groups = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> children1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> children2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    children1.add("Child_1");
    children1.add("Child_2");
    groups.add(children1);
    children2.add("Child_1");
    children2.add("Child_2");
    children2.add("Child_3");
    groups.add(children2);

    ExpListAdapter adapter = new ExpListAdapter(getActivity(), groups);
    mExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this my Adapter:

```
private class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mGroups;
    private Context mContext;

    public ExpListAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groups){
        mContext = context;
        mGroups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mGroups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_repair_tune_detail_item, null);

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_part_open_layout, null);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can see groups in `ExpandableListView` but when I click on the item it doesn't expanded.

Comment: Are you put parameter to child list? there was nothing at getchildView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

"implements OnChildClickListener, ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener"

at the class, where you will use your ExpandableListView.

After initializing your `ListView` you set the listener, where you implement your expandable listview.

```
customListView.setOnGroupClickListener(this);
customListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);
```

and override the methods

```
onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id)

onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id).
```

I guess that will fix your issue.

Comment: write full answer pls

Answer (score 1):

I think your group header layout 'activity_repair_tune_detail_item' may contain any focusable items like Checkbox or Button or Edittext. if it is true try by add `android:focusable="false"` to them. code uploaded by you is working properly to me.